# To change the style of a parent element when it is in the focus state of the child element input

Tags: css

I want to change the style of the parent element when there is a focus in the child element input.

I know that the original CSS doesn't work. I can use the state because it is React, but I want to know if there is a simpler way.

```html
<div className="container">
  <div className="input__container">
    <input type="text">
    </input>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
input:focus .container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`:focus-within`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-focus-within-pseudo) pseudo class (the `:has` pseudo class - which has less browser support isn't necessary here)

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within):

> The :focus-within CSS pseudo-class matches an element if the element
> or any of its descendants are focused.

Also, [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=focus-within) is very good

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid gold;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container:focus-within {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="input__container">
    <input type="text">
    </input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's the best way I've been looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `has()` pseude code. Please note, however, that it's [**not** supported by Firefox yet](https://caniuse.com/?search=has).

```css
.input__container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.input__container:has(input:focus) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="input__container">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```